# Not able to download the document file from firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

My chat app is working fine but when I'm sending any pdf or document file it is successfully uploaded in firebase storage and database. But when I try to download the file, it gives an error No Activity found to handle Intent.

Message Adapter Code

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder>
{
    private List<Messages> userMessagesList;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference usersRef;

    public MessageAdapter(List<Messages> userMessagesList)
    {
        this.userMessagesList = userMessagesList;
    }

    public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView senderMessageText, receiverMessageText;
        public CircleImageView receiverProfileImage;
        public ImageView messageSenderPicture, messageReceiverPicture;

        public MessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            senderMessageText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_message_text);
            receiverMessageText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiver_message_text);
            receiverProfileImage = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_profile_image);
            messageReceiverPicture = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_receiver_image_view);
            messageSenderPicture = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_sender_image_view);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_messages_layout, viewGroup, false);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        return new MessageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder, final int position)
    {
        String messageSenderID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Messages messages = userMessagesList.get(position);

        String fromUserID = messages.getFrom();
        String fromMessageType = messages.getType();

        usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(fromUserID);

        usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image"))
                {
                    String receiverImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                    Picasso.get().load(receiverImage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
            {

            }
        });

        messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        messageViewHolder.messageSenderPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        messageViewHolder.messageReceiverPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (fromMessageType.equals("text"))
        {
            if (fromUserID.equals(messageSenderID))
            {
                messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sender_messages_layout);
                messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setText(messages.getMessage() + "\n \n" + messages.getTime() + " - " + messages.getDate());
            }
            else
            {
                messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.receiver_messages_layout);
                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setText(messages.getMessage() + "\n \n" + messages.getTime() + " - " + messages.getDate());
            }
        }
        else if (fromMessageType.equals("image"))
        {
            if (fromUserID.equals(messageSenderID))
            {
                messageViewHolder.messageSenderPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Picasso.get().load(messages.getMessage()).into(messageViewHolder.messageSenderPicture);
            }
            else
            {
                messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                messageViewHolder.messageReceiverPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Picasso.get().load(messages.getMessage()).into(messageViewHolder.messageReceiverPicture);
            }
        }
        else if (fromMessageType.equals("pdf") || fromMessageType.equals("docx"))
        {
            if (fromUserID.equals(messageSenderID))
            {
                messageViewHolder.messageSenderPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Picasso.get()
                        .load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/whatsapp-11072000.appspot.com/o/Image%20Files%2Ffile.png?alt=media&token=664c6fd5-89fb-41c8-9db9-85b825deea40")
                        .into(messageViewHolder.messageSenderPicture);
            }
            else
            {
                messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                messageViewHolder.messageReceiverPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Picasso.get()
                        .load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/whatsapp-11072000.appspot.com/o/Image%20Files%2Ffile.png?alt=media&token=664c6fd5-89fb-41c8-9db9-85b825deea40")
                        .into(messageViewHolder.messageReceiverPicture);
            }
        }

        if (fromUserID.equals(messageSenderID))
        {
            messageViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    if (userMessagesList.get(position).getType().equals("pdf") || userMessagesList.get(position).getType().equals("docx"))
                    {
                        CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]
                                {
                                        "Delete for Me",
                                        "Download and View this Document",
                                        "Cancel",
                                        "Delete for Everyone"
                                };
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext());
                        builder.setTitle("Delete Message?");

                        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                            {
                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                                    deleteSentMessage(position, messageViewHolder);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                    messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                else if (i == 1)
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(userMessagesList.get(position).getMessage()));
                                    messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                else if (i == 3)
                                {
                                    deleteMessageForEveryone(position, messageViewHolder);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                    messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                    }
                    else if (userMessagesList.get(position).getType().equals("text"))
                    {
                        CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]
                                {
                                        "Delete for Me",
                                        "Cancel",
                                        "Delete for Everyone"
                                };
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext());
                        builder.setTitle("Delete Message?");

                        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                            {
                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                                    deleteSentMessage(position, messageViewHolder);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                    messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                else if (i == 2)
                                {
                                    deleteMessageForEveryone(position, messageViewHolder);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                    messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                    }
                    else if (userMessagesList.get(position).getType().equals("image"))
                    {
                        CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]
                                {
                                        "Delete for Me",
                                        "View this Image",
                                        "Cancel",
                                        "Delete for Everyone"
                                };
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext());
                        builder.setTitle("Delete Message?");

                        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                            {
                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                                    deleteSentMessage(position, messageViewHolder);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                    messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                else if (i == 1)
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext(), ImageViewerActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("url", userMessagesList.get(position).getMessage());
                                    messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                else if (i == 3)
                                {
                                    deleteMessageForEveryone(position, messageViewHolder);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                    messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            messageViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    if (userMessagesList.get(position).getType().equals("pdf") || userMessagesList.get(position).getType().equals("docx"))
                    {
                        CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]
                                {
                                        "Delete for Me",
                                        "Download and View this Document",
                                        "Cancel"
                                };
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext());
                        builder.setTitle("Delete Message?");

                        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                            {
                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                                    deleteReceiveMessage(position, messageViewHolder);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                    messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                else if (i == 1)
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(userMessagesList.get(position).getMessage()));
                                    messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                    }
                    else if (userMessagesList.get(position).getType().equals("text"))
                    {
                        CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]
                                {
                                        "Delete for Me",
                                        "Cancel"
                                };
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext());
                        builder.setTitle("Delete Message?");

                        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                            {
                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                                    deleteReceiveMessage(position, messageViewHolder);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                    messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                    }
                    else if (userMessagesList.get(position).getType().equals("image"))
                    {
                        CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]
                                {
                                        "Delete for Me",
                                        "View this Image",
                                        "Cancel"
                                };
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext());
                        builder.setTitle("Delete Message?");

                        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                            {
                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                                    deleteReceiveMessage(position, messageViewHolder);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                    messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                else if (i == 1)
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext(), ImageViewerActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("url", userMessagesList.get(position).getMessage());
                                    messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return userMessagesList.size();
    }


    private void deleteSentMessage(final int position, final MessageViewHolder holder)
    {
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        rootRef.child("Messages")
                .child(userMessagesList.get(position).getFrom())
                .child(userMessagesList.get(position).getTo())
                .child(userMessagesList.get(position).getMessageID())
                .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
            {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "Deleted Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "Error Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void deleteReceiveMessage(final int position, final MessageViewHolder holder)
    {
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        rootRef.child("Messages")
                .child(userMessagesList.get(position).getTo())
                .child(userMessagesList.get(position).getFrom())
                .child(userMessagesList.get(position).getMessageID())
                .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
            {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "Deleted Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "Error Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void deleteMessageForEveryone(final int position, final MessageViewHolder holder)
    {
        final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        rootRef.child("Messages")
                .child(userMessagesList.get(position).getTo())
                .child(userMessagesList.get(position).getFrom())
                .child(userMessagesList.get(position).getMessageID())
                .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
            {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    rootRef.child("Messages")
                            .child(userMessagesList.get(position).getFrom())
                            .child(userMessagesList.get(position).getTo())
                            .child(userMessagesList.get(position).getMessageID())
                            .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                        {
                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "Deleted Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "Error Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Manifest file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="rishabh.example.whatsapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ImageViewerActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChatActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PhoneLoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".GroupChatActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FindFriendsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error is throwing No Activity found to handle Intent on line

```
messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

My logcat error is

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@8126f0 }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2066)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1720)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5258)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5216)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5587)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5555)
    at rishabh.example.whatsapp.MessageAdapter$3$1.onClick(MessageAdapter.java:317)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1222)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:330)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1219)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3230)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4186)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7592)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: Post detailed error log.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: There are 13 lines of `messageViewHolder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);`, could you please specify which one is crashing?

Comment: Line no 197 and 317 of message adapter.

Answer (score 0):

**First solution**

Url addresses must start with HTTP:// or HTTPS://

So, check if your download URL is correct.

**Second solution**

Try to add this to manifest

```
    <provider
    android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
    android:authorities="com.PACKAGE.NAME.firebaseinitprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:initOrder="100"/>
    <service
    android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
    android:exported="false">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.storage.StorageRegistrar"
    android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
    </service>
```